# How do I create a keybinding (Ctrl + O) in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm wanting to create a keybinding in Kivy (Ctrl + O) that I can attach an event to. I see that the Kivy Inspector module is doing something similar but I'm not sure how to replicate the functionality.

I'd like to have the keybinding work on all of the Kivy application so I guess that it must bind to the window/root widget.

Has anyone done this before? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As you say the inspector module does exactly what you are looking for, so y not open the code and find out? It's Python after all :).

This is the file [inspector.py](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/modules/inspector.py)

Searching for `ctrl` as the shortcut the inspector uses is 'ctrl+e' get's us [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/modules/inspector.py#L339).::

```
def keyboard_shortcut(self, win, scancode, *largs):
    modifiers = largs[-1]
    if scancode == 101 and modifiers == ['ctrl']:
        self.activated = not self.activated
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

It seems like this is listening to keyboard and checking if the input matches 'ctrl' and 'e'

```
if scancode == 101 and modifiers == ['ctrl']:
```

However we don't know how/from where this function is called? So let's search for the function name::

```
 `keyboard_shortcut`
```

We get [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/modules/inspector.py#L475).

```
win.bind(children=ctx.inspector.on_window_children,
        on_keyboard=ctx.inspector.keyboard_shortcut)
```

win is a instance of window as we want to bind to a keyboard shortcut globally we are binding to the `on_keyboard` event of the Window.

What is this `on_keyboard` event of Window? Let's [search for `window`](http://kivy.org/docs/search.html?check_keywords=yes&area=default&q=window#) in kivy documentation.

The fourth link [kivy.core.window.Keyboard](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html?highlight=window#kivy.core.window.Keyboard) (Python class, in Window) seems interesting.
Following that link It seems they even have a example of using Window.keyboard and also explain the `on_keyboard` event [here](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html?highlight=window#kivy.core.window.WindowBase).

Following all of the resources above you should be able to bind to a shortcut globally so as to react to it.

Hope this is Helps.